# How to properly store and share docker host access?

Tags: docker, docker-machine, docker-swarm, docker-secrets

I followed a docker-machine tutorial to setup a docker swarm in the cloud. I had setup a bunch of replicas and life is good. Now I need to give my teammates access to this docker swarm. How do I do that?

Should I share docker certificate files? Can each team member have an individual set of certificate files? Is there any way to setup OAuth or other form of SSO?

Answer (score 0):

The Docker daemon doesn't do any extended client auth.

You can [generate certificate's for each client from the CA that signed the swarm certificate](https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/https/#create-a-ca-server-and-client-keys-with-openssl), which is probably the minimum you want. Access to Docker is `root` access to the host so best not to hand out direct access to everyone, or outside of development.

For any extended authentication and authorisation you would need to put a broker between the Docker API and your clients. The easiest way to do this is to use a higher level management platform like [Rancher](http://rancher.com/rancher/) or [Shipyard](http://shipyard-project.com/), that can manage the swarm for you.

[Mesos](https://mesos.apache.org/)/[Marathon](https://mesosphere.github.io/marathon/)/[Mesosphere](https://mesosphere.com/) and [Kubernetes](https://kubernetes.io/) are simliar in function but have more of their own idea of what clustering is.